# Using DomElement to set [class] attribute for AMP html

Tags: php, dom, amp-html

Is there anyway around `->setAttribute` not allowing me to set an attribute named `[class]`? I have the following code:

```
    $success = $doc->createElement('span', 'You have been successfully subscribed');
    $success->setAttribute('class', 'hide');
    $success->setAttribute('[class]', 'ampState.success'); // error here
    $form->appendChild($success);
```

But when attempting to run this, I get

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught DOMException: Invalid Character Error in <path>
```

Is there a lower level manually method I can use to set this attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I ended up using involved creating a pseudo-tag, which I could *str_replace* after:

```
$success = $doc->createElement('span', 'You have been successfully subscribed');
$success->setAttribute('class', 'hide');

// [class] => pseudo-class
$success->setAttribute('pseudo-class', 'ampState.success'); 

$form->appendChild($success);
```

Then at the very end, I create generate all my HTML and perform a str-replace on that pseudo class to change it back:

```
// get all HTML inside <body></body>
$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
foreach($body->childNodes as $childNode)
{
    $innerHTML .= $childNode->ownerDocument->saveHTML($childNode);
}

// replace pseudo-class with [class]
$innerHTML = str_replace('pseudo-class', '[class]', $innerHTML);
```